# Is there any way my app can display the MMS from which it was launched?

Tags: ios

The desired scenario is this:

1) The user receives an MMS which contains a combination of images and text
2) My app is launched if the user taps on the MMS
3) When my app launches it initially displays the same MMS that the user tapped to launch my app.

1) and 2) should be straightforward to achieve using a URL displayed with the MMS (though it would be great if the URL that launches the app was not visible, if that is possible).

3) Looks like its not possible, but maybe people have some ingenious suggestions.

When the app is launched the following gets called by the caller:

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation).
> ```

But it seems as annotation is empty as   NSString *description = [annotation description] displays nothing if passed to a UIAlertView.

So it seems there's no information about the MMS passed to the app when its launched via the annotation.

Are there any workarounds to achieve my desired outcome? For example my app doesn't initially display a window/view so the previous view of the MMS remains visible, or its possible somehow for my app to take a screenshot of the MMS before it vanishes from view and display the screen shot, or ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not passed in the URL, no. You cannot access another app's data unless it is explicitly passed to your app.

**Edit**

The annotation property is used by [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304), it is not for you to pass along additional information as it alludes to.

Also, you have no control of taking a screenshot before your app is launched, this would be a serious security flaw in the OS if random apps could invoke screenshots and access said screenshots.

Comment: Which is as I thought, hence wondering if there are any other possible solutions, such as those two mentioned (although I'm almost certain those are non starters).

Comment: Edited to address the thought of using `annotation` and screenshots